# Displaying/Rendering XML in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to display a XML which will be fetched from backend in a EXT JS panel and window.
I tried creating a new window and opening a new window and assigning the document type but it's not getting properly formatted liek it does when we open in IE. Also is there a way I can open it in a EXT JS window instead of a browser window. My XML is dynamic which could be different XML (with different root node) everytime. Here is what I tried so far with no luck

```js
myXmlWindow = window.open('', 'FullView', 'toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes');
myXmlWindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"resources/XMLDisplay.css\" type=\"text/css\"><center><table class=\"data\"><tr><th>" + xmlString + "</td></tr></table></center>");
```

Can anyone help me with this. All I need to do is display XML just like below screen shot in IE

[image: Sample XML viewed in IE]

Here is my XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Record>
  <SYS_ID>238</SYS_ID>
  <SYS_DSC>This is a test XML</SYS_DSC>
  <GTMU_ID>6</GTMU_ID>
  <LOC_ID>3760</LOC_ID>
  <SLS_UNIT_ID>0090008924</SLS_UNIT_ID>
  <RLTNSHP_TYP_CDV>15</RLTNSHP_TYP_CDV>
  <RLTNSHP_TYP_NM>This is a test XML</RLTNSHP_TYP_NM>
  <RLTNSHP_STRT_DT>1985-12-29T00:00:00-06:00</RLTNSHP_STRT_DT>
  <RLTNSHP_END_DT>9999-12-31T00:00:00-06:00</RLTNSHP_END_DT>
</Record>
```

If I do below as suggested by Yellen,

```js
var w= window.open('data:text/xml,'+encodeURI(xmlString));
```

I am getting below error

[image: Error]

Comment: You xml is invalid. Here is your correct xml -   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Record> <SYS_ID>238</SYS_ID>  <SYS_DSC>This is a test XML</SYS_DSC>  <GTMU_ID>6</GTMU_ID>  <LOC_ID>760</LOC_ID>  <SLS_UNIT_ID>0090008924</SLS_UNIT_ID>  <RLTNSHP_TYP_CDV>15</RLTNSHP_TYP_CDV>  <RLTNSHP_TYP_NM>This is a test XML</RLTNSHP_TYP_NM>  <RLTNSHP_STRT_DT>1985-12-29T00:00:00-06:00</RLTNSHP_STRT_DT>  <RLTNSHP_END_DT>9999-12-31T00:00:00-06:00</RLTNSHP_END_DT></Record>

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: I think I introduced the mismatched tags I encountered. But the xml I posted works.

Comment: Check here - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lld I'm using the same xml

Comment: Also, please refer to think link for uri encoding. It'll help http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Comment: There is no problem with this xml. You may have introduced some errors when converting to string

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lld

You can simply call a `window.open()` with the parameter `('data:text/xml,' + xmlText)`, you can also pass other window options as you want. This will just open a new tab with the xml content.

xml in chrome -

[image: xml in chrome]

Comment: Ext.window.Window is just a special Ext.panel.Panel and is not a browser window object

Comment: Hi Yellen, when I try to do this I am getting error:  This webpage is not available

ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Are you encoding the xmlText?

Comment: Also, how is your xml?

Comment: Yes I am..I can see the complete XML in console.log() but when I display it throws and error something like  :-                                   xmlString= "<?xml version='1.0' ?>" + document;
 console.log(xmlString);
 var w= window.open('','FullView','data:text/xml,'+encodeURI(xmlString));

Comment: Is there a way to display this in EXT Panel itself without parsing ?

Comment: As far as I can understand, it can be displayed as simple text inside an Ext Panel. Even if you escape the brackets, you might now get the desired output you desire.

Comment: Are there any special characters in your xml? Did you try with the simple xml in my test code?

Comment: yes..the XML in your code works. I removed few characters from my XML and now I am getting some parsing error. Updating screenshots in my question

Comment: Updated the question Yellen. Please help me to find out where am I doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an iframe. ExtJS provides an extension for this with Ext.ux.IFrame you should be able to nest your xml into an Ext.Window.

```
var xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Employee><Id>22</Id></Employee>';

xmlText = encodeURI(xmlText);

var myWindow = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    layout: "fit",
    items: [Ext.create("Ext.ux.IFrame", {
        src: 'data:text/xml,' + xmlText
    })]
});

myWindow.show();
```

Comment: I think the content of the IFrame will be the parsed xml values and will not actually display it as an xml. The window will only display 22 in the content.

Comment: That's correct. The iFame parses the XML document and display just the content

Comment: Maybe you can use an alternative xml output generator? Like [xmlspectrum](https://github.com/pgfearo/xmlspectrum)

Comment: @SimonHoss - I think, I'll thank you for xmlspectrum. Something I can use. :)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to enclose your XML in tags something like this

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lo9

Not exactly how I wanted but sort of a workaround

Comment: I thought you wanted it displayed like the picture that you attached - with those expand-collapse options!! Just displaying the content of the xml as text is really different.

Comment: Yes that was the original intent..but I gave up on that.so I will not call my solution a answer but something workable/work around. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I'm just confused how that xml gave error in your case.

Comment: I have no idea.Couldn't figure that out. I tried to copy that XML in Altova and that is also giving error like "Some additional content in the end " but I couldn't see any.

Comment: That's really a bad XML then. you should get it fixed.